# Shiro - Don't transmit password to server

Tags: authentication, ssl, shiro

I'm not much of a security expert, so I've implemented user authentication for my Client+REST API using Apache Shiro.  Everything works, however I'm a bit confused about one aspect: Shiro seems to require me to transmit the user's password to the server for authentication.

I have a endpoint, /user/auth that my frontend (angular) POSTs login info to, which then creates a UsernamePasswordToken and calls Subject.login() with it, and Shiro then takes care of querying my db for the 'password' string it generates (using DefaultPasswordService.encryptPassword()) and comparing it with the password the user POSTed.  This is all going to be over SSL once I put it on a public server, however it still seems strange to me to be sending the user's password to the server every login, instead of hashing it somehow.

I'd thought the default practice was to hash the password on the client side, and then send that to the server?  Or does this just not matter anymore once you've got SSL?  Would it be better to have the client hash the password before sending it, even when registering, so that the server would only ever store the hash?  I know Shiro isn't storing the password in plaintext, so I assume its storing a hash in my database, but it could just be encrypted with something for all I know.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am trying to solve the same thing.

Comment: No.  Although it rubs me the wrong way, I have currently left this as is, since no one here or at my job has had any problems with it

Comment: I mean, as far as solutions go, I'm fairly certain that sending a unique hash to the client for them to hash their password with before sending it back would work just fine, I'm just not sure if it would actually make stuff any better or just stay the same

Comment: That was my thinking as well!